# Check if image's resolution is more than 16 megapixels in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I'm trying to check if an image has a maximum resolution of 16 megapixels or not.
Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("image.jpg")
width, height = im.size
resolution = width * height
if resolution > (16 * 1000000):
    print("Image has a resolution greater than 16 megapixels.")
else:
    print("Image has a resolution less than or equal to 16 megapixels.")
```

But I'm not sure if this is working as I don't know what megapixels represent.

Comment: Your definition seems to align with my intuition and https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/40442/how-many-pixels-in-a-megapixel

Comment: @JonSG, Is my code fine ?

Comment: Seems like it might be (other than the initial `"\`"` that I expect is just a formatting blip).  Do you get an error when you run it?

Comment: @JonSG, Can you tell me what 16 mega pixels be into width x height pixels ?

Comment: As I understand it, when you multiply the height in pixels by the width in pixels, a megapixel is about a million. a 16 megapixel image is one whose height multiplied by width is about 16 million. if the image was square that would be `4000x4000` but might also be `2000x8000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided code correctly determines whether or not the image resolution exceeds 16 megapixels (1 [megapixel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel#Megapixel) = 1 million pixels).

However, the relationship between the number of megapixels and image dimensions is not direct.

The number of megapixels indicates the total number of pixels in the image but does not indicate the width and height. This is due to the fact that these measurements are dependent on the [aspect ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image)), which is the ratio of width to height.

Given that, it is impossible to convert megapixels to image dimensions without a fixed aspect ratio.